# part of a React component CSS missing after deployment

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment

I can't find the solution: how it looks on localhost (which is what I want): [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZDMz.png) and how it looks after deployment with heroku:[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJYTH.png) . I even added some `!important` in my CSS file but it didn't change anything. Seems that on localhost all the css is applied which means the import is working and the classNames are found, but not after deployment (only the send button + error messages CSS is applied)...am I missing something obvious ? Thank you.

ContactForm.js

```
import styles from "./ContactForm.module.css";

    return (
        <Col>
            <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendEmail)} id='contact-form'>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            name="email"
                            placeholder="Email"
                            className={`mt-2 py-1 ${styles.formRowContent}`}
                            {...register("email", {
                                required: 'Email invalide',
                                pattern: /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
                            })}
                        />
                        {
                            errors.email &&
                            <span className={styles.errorMessage}>
                                {errors.email.message}
                            </span>
                        }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            name="subject"
                            placeholder="Sujet"
                            className={`mt-2 py-1 ${styles.formRowContent}`}
                            {...register("subject", {
                                required: 'Veuillez indiquer le sujet de votre message',
                            })}
                        />
                        {
                            errors.subject &&
                            <span className={styles.errorMessage}>
                                {errors.subject.message}
                            </span>
                        }

                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <textarea
                            type="text"
                            name="message"
                            placeholder="Votre message"
                            className={`${styles.formRowContent} mt-2 py-1`}
                            {...register("message", {
                                required: 'Veuillez écrire votre message',
                                minLength: {
                                    value: 20,
                                    message: 'Votre message doit contenir 20 caractères minimum'
                                }
                            })}
                            rows={5}
                        >
                        </textarea>
                        {
                            errors.message &&
                            <span className={styles.errorMessage}>
                                {errors.message.message}
                            </span>
                        }

                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row className="text-end">
                    <Col>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            value="Envoyer"
                            id={styles.btnSubmit}>
                            Envoyer
                        </button>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </form>
        </Col>
    )
}

export default ContactForm;
```

ContactForm.module.css

```
input.formRowContent, textarea.formRowContent{
    background-color: black !important;
    color:white !important;
    width:100% !important;
}

#btnSubmit{
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    padding:0.3em;
}

.errorMessage{
    color:red;
    font-weight: bolder;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: just add - import "./ContactForm.module.css"; And className="mt-2 py-1 formRowContent".. same for button and error message. className="btnSubmit". className="errorMessage"